# Problema con mostrar mapview en android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

Estoy intentando poner unas marcas al map view pero no lo consigo, la app me crashea, no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.
Tengo la apikey instalada y los permisos dados en el android manifest.

Tras debugar me he dado cuenta que la linea de Mapa.this.googleMap = googleMap siempre esta a null por lo que no sigue al for de ubicaciones.

Por tanto, solo me tira por el log la traza 1 y la 5.

Alguien ve el fallo??

Aqui esta el codigo de error:
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.p, PID: 25486 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "40.445616, -3.699297"`

```
public class Mapa extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MapController mapController;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    // Obtener el ArrayList de ubicaciones desde el Intent
    ArrayList<String> ubicaciones;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

        // Obtener el MapView desde el layout
        MapView mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        // Crear una instancia de MapController
        mapController = new MapController(this, mapView);

        // Obtener el ArrayList de ubicaciones desde el Intent
        ubicaciones = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ARRAYLIST_UBICACIONES");
        Log.d("Mapa", "TRAZA 1");

        //metodo para saber que se el mapa esta inicializado correctamente
        mapController.setOnMapReadyCallback(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                Mapa.this.googleMap = googleMap;
                // Agregar los marcadores

                Log.d("Mapa", "TRAZA 3");
                for (String ubicacion : ubicaciones) {
                    String[] partes = ubicacion.split("/"); //aqui entra la fila completa
                    String[] coordenadas = partes[2].split(",");
                    double latitud = Double.parseDouble(coordenadas[0]); //aqui se divide en partes y coje la 2, es decir 36.71....
                    double longitud = Double.parseDouble(coordenadas[1]);
                    mapController.addMarker(partes[0], partes[1], latitud, longitud);
                    Log.d("Mapa", "TRAZA 4");

                }
                // Zoom al primer marcador agregado
                if (!ubicaciones.isEmpty()) {
                    String[] partes = ubicaciones.get(0).split("/");
                    double latitud = Double.parseDouble(partes[2]);
                    double longitud = Double.parseDouble(partes[3]);
                    mapController.zoomToLocation(latitud, longitud, 15);
                }
                Log.d("Mapa", "Traza 5");

            }
        });
        Log.d("Mapa", "Traza 6");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mapController != null) {
            mapController.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mapController != null) {
            mapController.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mapController != null) {
            mapController.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Adjunto tambien el MapController.java con el que manipulo los puntos:

```
public class MapController implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MapController.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private OnMapReadyCallback mapReadyCallback;

    public void setOnMapReadyCallback(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        this.mapReadyCallback = callback;
    }


    public MapController(Context context, MapView mapView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mapView = mapView;

        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady");
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        this.googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        if (mapReadyCallback != null) {
            mapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
        }
    }

    public void addMarker(String locationName, String address, double latitude, double longitude) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(locationName)
                    .snippet(address);
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            marker.setTag(locationName);
            zoomToLocation(latitude, longitude, 15);

        }
    }

    public void zoomToLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int zoom) {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        }
    }

    public void findAddress(String address) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address location = addresses.get(0);
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                String locationName = location.getFeatureName();
                String fullAddress = location.getAddressLine(0);
                addMarker(locationName, fullAddress, latitude, longitude);
                zoomToLocation(latitude, longitude, 25);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while geocoding", e);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        // Do something when the map is clicked
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        String locationName = (String) marker.getTag();
        // Do something when a marker is clicked
        return true;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El error :

> NumberFormatException: For input string: "40.445616, -3.699297"

indica que estás tratando de realizar una conversión a `Double` con un `String` incorrecto:

```
Double latitud = Double.parseDouble("40.445616, -3.699297");
```

Necesitas obtener el array donde se obtengan los valores de latitud y longitud y ahora si podrás convertirlos a `Double`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
           ...
           ...
           for (String ubicacion : ubicaciones) {
                String[] partes = ubicacion.split("/"); //aqui entra la fila completa
                String[] coordenadas = partes[2].split(",");

                //Obtiene array donde se almacena latitud y longitud
                 String[] latlong = coordenadas.split(",");

                double latitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]); //valor: 40.445616
                double longitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]); //valor: -3.699297"
                mapController.addMarker(partes[0], partes[1], latitud, longitud);
                Log.d("Mapa", "TRAZA 4");

            }
           ...
           ...
```